# Installing the qtftp module in Qt 5.6.0

Tags: c++, qt, module, qtftp

I'm trying to install qftp but it does not really work. I first recovered the sources on github. Then I copied the sources to Qt's src folder and renamed the "qtftp" folder, then run the Perl syncqt.pl file to generate the headers and others. Then I did a qmake, then a make.

I then copied the QFtp folder created in the qtftp include folder into the Qt include folder. Then in the .pro file of my project, I made an include of the qt_ftp.pri file created in the qtftp folder and I added QT + = ftp. I did a qmake, everything is fine. #include  does not output any error.

The self completion completes nickel for Qftp. But when compiling my project I have an error of the type "undefined reference to 'Qqft :: qftp (Qobject *)". I'm stuck, I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. You just had to modify the qt_ftp.pri file located in the \ modules folder by putting "include (.. \ mkspecs \ modules \ qt_lib_ftp.pri)" in the first line of the file

Answer (score 0):

`undefined reference to 'Qqft :: qftp (Qobject *)` means that the linker (for some reason) cannot resolve the function call to `qftp` you made in your code.

- Maybe adding `QT += ftp` does not cause QMake to add the QFTP-Library to the linker call in your Makefile. Have a look at your makefile if `libqftp.so` (or, if you are using Windows: `qftp.dll`) or something like this is present.
- If the call to `qftp` does not come from your own code but from some other library you're using, it's possible that the order of libraries in the linker call is wrong. If a linker finds an unresolved symbol in library A, it only looks for it in the libraries mentioned **after** A in the linker call. If this is the case you will have to find out how you can change the order of libraries in the linker call generated by qmake.

Comment: I tried to review everything you just said but the problem persists. I do not know if I installed the module incorrectly or what